# Error trying to add cors.json file in firebase project

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I came accross an error when trying to add cors.json file to my Firebase project.
I have a budget app created with React and powered by authentification and cloud firestore and provided by Firebase.

On my localhost everything works fine: I sign in, add expenses etc. But once I deployed my app to render.com I stumbled onto an error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fbudget-app-react-3f8a6%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=2186&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&zx=qv2osyi6ocl&t=1' from origin 'https://bud-app.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>
> logger.ts:115 [2023-08-03T17:41:34.095Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.23.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

First solution that I tried was to add cors.json file via cloud shell terminal and editor:

1. I created JSON file with the following config

```js
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

2. Entered terminal and typed command where budget-app-react-3f8a6.appspot.com is my storageBucket in firebaseConfig

> gsutil cors set cors.json gs://budget-app-react-3f8a6.appspot.com

And then I received an error:

> Setting CORS on gs://budget-app-react-3f8a6.appspot.com/...
> NotFoundException: 404 The specified bucket does not exist.

Second I tried to solve the problem with gcloud CLI. After following the documentation step-by-step I received basically the same error:

> gs://budget-app-react-3f8a6 not found: 404.

Maybe someone could help me with solving this CORS problem I have?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `gs://budget-app-react-3f8a6 not found: 404` means the bucket you want to use isn't available. To fix this:

1. Go to your Firebase settings.
2. Click on your project.
3. Choose `Storage` on the left.
4. Select the `Browser` tab.
5. Find the correct bucket name under `Bucket.`

If the name is correct, check if the bucket exists using this terminal command:

```
gsutil ls gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Replace `BUCKET\_NAME` with your Firebase storage bucket's name.

If the bucket doesn't exist, create it using the gsutil tool:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Install gsutil by typing:

```
pip install gsutil
```

3. Create the bucket:

```
gsutil mb gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Replace BUCKET_NAME with your Firebase storage bucket's name.

Once the bucket is ready, set CORS:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Navigate to the folder with cors.json.
3. Run this command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Replace `BUCKET\_NAME` with your Firebase storage bucket's name.

If you still face issues, verify your permissions to change CORS in the Firebase settings under IAM & Admin.